# $A$ be $3 \times 3$ matrix with eigenvalues $1,-1,3$. Then which of the following options is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be $3 \times 3$ matrix with eigenvalues $1,-1,3$. Then which of the following options is correct?

> 1. $A^2+A$ is non-singular
> 2. $A^2-A$ is non-singular
> 3. $A^2+3A$ is non-singular
> 4. $A^2-3A$ is non-singular

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you wrote before though... that A satisfies its characteristic equation. This is true if A is diagonal. I don't think it's true in general. The rest of what you wrote looks fine.

Comment: @AmeetSharma you are wrong here. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is a multiple of $(x-1)(x+1)(x-3)$, by Cayley-Hamilton, $(A-I)(A+I)(A-3I)=0$.

Comment: Ah. I see. Thanks. Sorry about that. I'm learning matrix analysis now and haven't reached the Cayley-Hamilton theorem yet.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation of $A$ is a multiple of  $(x+1)(x-1)(x-3)=0$ and $A$ satisfies its characteristic equation.
S0, $(A-I)(A+I)(A-3I)=0$  Also, $\det (A) \neq 0$ as its eigenvalues are all non-zero. Looking at option 3, we see that
$\det (A^2+3A)=\det(A). \det(A+3I) \neq 0$ as $\det (A) \neq 0$ and $\det (A+3I) \neq 0$ as $-3$ is not an eigenvalue of 
$A$. So, option (3) is the right choice.